# Not able to get required output using yield

Tags: ruby, yield

I want to print the value 5 using the `ablock` as shown below. I tried using `ablock {|x, y| puts "answer:#{x+2*y}"}`. But it does not display anything in the irb.

```
def ablock
  i = 1
  j = 2
  yield(i, j)
  i = 3
  j = 4
end
```

Comment: Looks fine. It should print `answer:5`

Comment: works for me as well

Answer (score 1):

it should work fine

```
2.1.1 :001 > def ablock
2.1.1 :002?>     i = 1
2.1.1 :003?>     j = 2
2.1.1 :004?>     yield(i, j)
2.1.1 :005?>     i = 3
2.1.1 :006?>     j = 4
2.1.1 :007?>   end
 => :ablock 
2.1.1 :008 > ablock {|x, y| puts "answer:#{x+2*y}"}
answer:5
 => 4 
2.1.1 :009 >
```

Comment: yeah...it works fine...looks like the ablock function did not get created when I pasted the method in irb...I tried again and it worked..